# Conditional validation not working for one field

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I've 4 fields as shown below:
[image]

radioGroup1 is required if comboBox2 value and radioGroup4 & radio1 are blank. The validation message is suppose to go away if only one of 3 radio's is selected

If I select radioGroup1 or radio1 and update page, the validation message does not display.

If I select radioGroup4 and update page, the validation message is still displayed.

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Here is a validation code for radioGroup1:

```
var comboBox2:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspSelectOneMenu = getComponent("comboBox2");
var radio1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputRadio = getComponent("radio1");
var radioGroup4:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspSelectOneRadio = getComponent("radioGroup4");
var radioGroup3:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspSelectOneRadio = getComponent("radioGroup3");
if(comboBox2.getValue()!==''){
   if(radioGroup3.getValue()==null){
    if(radioGroup4.getValue()==null && radio1.getValueAsString()==''){
        return true;
        }else {
        return false;
        }
    }

}
```

In second image there is a computed field capturing value of radioGroup4.
What am I doing wrong? When page is refreshed, radioGroup4.getValue() works in computed field but not in the validation script for radioGroup3.

When any one of 3 radio control selected, the other two are disabled thru script and it is working without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue as follows:

1. radioGroup4 was executing script and doing full update in the onChange event. Changed it to onClick event
2. It need two clicks in the radioGroup4 and required message for radioGroup3 vanishes.

This is not a perfect solution but I've to leave with it until I found perfect one.